# Encountered invalid root element name 'HTML'. 'root' is the only allowed root element name

Tags: c#, wcf

i am using msdn sample code and it has jsonp wrapper files you can find the code here

of this [article](http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/) and MSDN article JSON with Padding (AJAX)

but when i run the code it throw me this error:

`Encountered invalid root element name 'HTML'. 'root' is the only allowed root element name`

what does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you've made some kind of web request that is expecting to get some kind of XML data back but instead it is getting HTML data back.  The usual cause is a messed up URL.  If your URL were correct, then XML would be returned as expected.  Since it is messed up you end up getting back HTML (probably an error page at that).

Check your URLs to make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to similar problem. In my case, I was getting similar error, when my service was returning raw JSON, that is to say it was returning a Stream which represented this JSON.

The error was: Encountered invalid root element name 'Binary'. 'root' is the only allowed root element name.

The problem is that the MS provided example uses JsonWriter to take convert the message to JSON, but this writer expects that your message consists of JSON objects which he can convert to Stream. In my case the message was compose of binary data, so instead of one "root" element I was having "Binary" element.

I got over this issue by modifying classes provided by the MS sample. Basically I check the format of the message - if it is JSON I can still use the JsonWriter, if it is Binary, I have to take a different approach. In your case the message is in HTML format (I am not sure how do you serve it), but you will find a different way to get the body of the message.

I wrote a blog post about my issue here: http://hoonzis.blogspot.com/2011/07/provide-jsonp-with-your-wcf-services.html

Hope it helps a bit, Honza

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error message but in a different scenario. I was adding JSON support to a WCF web service that only supported XML.

Specifically I wanted to return the error messages object in JSON also.
I had a class that was implementing `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler`. Within the `ProvideFault` method I was setting the `WebBodyFormateMessageProperty to the corresponding one wither, XML or JSON based on what it was passed in the accept header. I was also setting the content type accordingly. What I was missing was using the correct serializer for each case

```
    Dim webBodyFormatMessageProp As Channels.WebBodyFormatMessageProperty
    Dim contentType As String
    Dim serializer As XmlObjectSerializer
    If WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json Then
        webBodyFormatMessageProp = New System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebContentFormat.Json)
        contentType = "application/json"
        serializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(MyErroClass))
    Else
        webBodyFormatMessageProp = New System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebContentFormat.Xml)
        contentType = "text/xml"
        serializer = New DataContractSerializer(GetType(MyErroClass))
    End If

    Dim detail = faultException.[GetType]().GetProperty("Detail").GetGetMethod().Invoke(faultException, Nothing)
    fault = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(version, "", detail, serializer)
    fault.Properties.Add(System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, webBodyFormatMessageProp)

    Dim httpResponseMessageProp = New System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageProperty()
    httpResponseMessageProp.Headers(System.Net.HttpResponseHeader.ContentType) = contentType
    httpResponseMessageProp.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
    httpResponseMessageProp.StatusDescription = [error].Message

    fault.Properties.Add(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, httpResponseMessageProp)
```

Apologize for the VB.net but that is what I am currently working on.